# Can Time Machine send an email notification when it's completed?

Tags: backup, mac-osx-server, time-machine

I'm running a number of servers, all with Time Machine Capsules configured on them. The thing is, these are headless servers, and I would like to know if it is possible to have an email sent out to me, whenever a backup is successful, or even unsuccessful.

Any hints and tips would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even Apple discourages use of Time Machine as a server backup. I would recommend another solution, starting from simple `rsync` to LBackup, BRU, Arcserve, Netvault etc.

Comment: I have access to online backup storage, but the particular client that owns this setup, likes time capsules. I just hate pulling my hair out trying to log in every few days making sure all the servers are at least running their backups

Comment: I went with another solution - so I guess BobC was right

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a few options out there:

https://tmnotifier.com
http://www.carnationsoftware.com/TM_Error_Log_WebPage.html

Also take a look at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31444/send-background-email-alert-if-time-machine-backup-fails